# IPC message queue

Tags: c, ipc

I am creating two apps (client and server) in c to communicate via IPC message queues.
The server have to operate for many clients using only one queue. Clients' ids have to be provided for the server as the Command Line arguments, as well as the id for each client. Clients are recognized by a mesg_type.

I have a problem to receive messages from all clients - I can receive the message a few times from client A, then a few times from client B, a few times from client A and so on. I think that the problem is in the following part of the code:

```
int status;
key_t key;
int msgid; 

for(int i=0;i<argc-1;i++){
    clients_ids[i]=atoi(argv[i+1]);
}

key = ftok(".", 50);
msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  
if (msgid == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "msgget failed: %d\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
  
do{
 for (int k=0;k<=argc-2;k++){
    status = msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), clients_ids[k], 0);
    if(status != -1){
    type = message.mesg_type;
    strcpy(mesg, message.mesg_text);
    }
}

 printf("Message received (from id: %d): %s ",type, mesg);
```

Can you please advise me what should I change?

Comment: You should include the _full_ (minimised) code needed to demonstrated the problem, and a specific scenario of input, desired output, current wrong output, and a description of what exactly is going wrong. I don't think it's worth readers' time to speculate about abridged code.

Answer (score 1):

move the call to `printf()` to inside the `for (int k=0;k<=argc-2;k++){` loop.  then all messages will be displayed.